How to add this conditions to alert ? - Pine script tradingview
My condition is i want the alert to notify me when there is a candle that closes more than 1% in upward or downward move.
i tried various things but could'nt figure it out. i want the exact pine script to notify me when my condition is met.

You can use the ta.roc for that.

Calculates the percentage of change (rate of change) between the
current value of source and its value length bars ago.

chg = ta.roc(close, 1)
alert_cond = barstate.isconfirmed and (chg > 1.00)

